# Selecting Nth Row of Filtered Data

Tags: excel, vba

I want to tag specified lines of a table for sample review.

Due to the volume of data, running repeated loops over the entire population would result in unacceptably long runtimes (as I have to tag specified sub-populations for QA sampling).

The approach I have taken is to bring in the table, and then filter based on the population I want to sample (for example, filter by location, by product, and by analyst) and then select a percentage of that population for sampling by putting "Sample" into a column.

I have tried several permutations of the code.

The first, where I used the Areas function, threw 1004 errors if there was more than one row.

The second gives strange row selections, including selecting non-hidden rows (and I can't understand why it is picking the rows that it is, as they don't seem to be correctly offset even if it was going by "all rows" not just visible rows).

```
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SourceDataTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Product1"
        sectionCount = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SourceDataTable").AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        If sectionCount = 0 Then sectionSampleSize = 0 Else sectionSampleSize = Int((sectionCount / 10) + 0.5)
        MsgBox ("Analyst " & analystLoopCellRef.Value & " ecomm section count is " & sectionCount & " and sample size is " & sectionSampleSize)

        Do While sectionSampleSize > 0

            sectionLoopRand = Int(sectionCount * Rnd + 1)

            MsgBox (sectionLoopRand)
'            MsgBox (ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SourceDataTable").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Columns(40).Rows(sectionLoopRand).Cells(1, 1).Value)

            If ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SourceDataTable").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns(40).Rows(sectionLoopRand).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Sample" Then
                MsgBox ("Sample overlap")
            Else
                ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SourceDataTable").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns(40).Rows(sectionLoopRand).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Sample"
'                MsgBox ("Sample address is " & ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SourceDataTable").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns(40).Rows(sectionLoopRand).Cells(1, 1).Address)
                sectionSampleSize = sectionSampleSize - 1
'                MsgBox ("Sample selected")
            End If


        Loop
```

Older version

```
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SourceDataTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Product1"
        sectionCount = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SourceDataTable").AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        If sectionCount = 0 Then sectionSampleSize = 0 Else sectionSampleSize = Int((sectionCount / 10) + 0.5)
        MsgBox ("Analyst " & analystLoopCellRef.Value & " ecomm section count is " & sectionCount & " and sample size is " & sectionSampleSize)

        Do While sectionSampleSize > 0

            sectionLoopRand = Int(sectionCount * Rnd + 1)

            MsgBox (sectionLoopRand)
'            MsgBox (ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SourceDataTable").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(sectionLoopRand).Columns(40).Cells(1, 1).Value)

            If ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SourceDataTable").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(sectionLoopRand).Columns(40).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Sample" Then
                MsgBox ("Sample overlap")
            Else
                ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SourceDataTable").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(sectionLoopRand).Columns(40).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Sample"
''                MsgBox ("Sample address is " & ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SourceDataTable").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(sectionLoopRand).Columns(40).Cells(1, 1).Address)
                sectionSampleSize = sectionSampleSize - 1
'                MsgBox ("Sample selected")
            End If


        Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Auto filters can create non-contiguous ranges with multiple areas which can be problematic for normal range methods. One way is to loop through the visible cells and build an array of the addresses (or rows). Then by selecting an array element at random you can get the address of a cell in the visible range. For example

```
Option Explicit
Sub mysample()

    Const TABLE_NAME = "SourceDataTable"
    Const FILTER_COL = 1
    Const TABLE_COL = 40 ' word sample added in table col 40

    Const SAMPLE_TERM = "Product1"
    Const SAMPLE_RATE = 10 ' 1 in 10 sampled
    Const LOOP_MAX = 10000 ' avoid infinite while loop

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject, rng As Range, t0 As Single
    t0 = Timer

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    ' apply filter and set rng to visible cells in filter col
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(TABLE_NAME)
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=FILTER_COL, Criteria1:=SAMPLE_TERM
    Set rng = tbl.Range.Columns(FILTER_COL).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Debug.Print rng.Address, rng.Cells.Count

    ' build myrows array of addresses from rng.cells
    Dim iCount As Integer, myrows() As String, cell As Range
    iCount = -1 ' myrows(0) will be header
    ReDim myrows(rng.Cells.Count)
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        iCount = iCount + 1
        myrows(iCount) = cell.Address
        'Debug.Print iCount, cell.Address, cell.Row
    Next

    ' determine sample size
    Dim iSampleSize As Integer
    If iCount > SAMPLE_RATE / 2 Then
        iSampleSize = Round(iCount / SAMPLE_RATE, 0)
    End If
    'Debug.Print iSampleSize

    ' select sample
    Dim n As Integer, x As Integer, z As Integer
    n = 0
    Do While n < iSampleSize

        ' pick one at random
        x = 1 + Int(Rnd * iCount) ' avoid header row 0
        'Debug.Print n, x

        ' update table if not previously chosen
        If Len(myrows(x)) > 0 Then
            ws.Range(myrows(x)).Offset(0, TABLE_COL - FILTER_COL) = "Sample"
            myrows(x) = "" ' avoid repeat
            n = n + 1
        End If

        z = z + 1 ' avoid endless loop
        If z > LOOP_MAX Then
            MsgBox "Max iterations in While Loop exceeded", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Loop
    MsgBox iSampleSize & " items selected from " & iCount, vbInformation, "Completed in " & Int(Timer - t0) & " secs"

End Sub
```